# Dual Boot Ubuntu issue - unable to access hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, touchpad

I am dual booting Linux with preinstalled windows 10 for the first time. I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.7 on my system. I am having the following issues:

1. When I click on "try ubuntu without installing", I land on the ubuntu homepage. My touchpad doesn't work but my keyboard does.
2. There is just one screen resolution option available under the "Displays" tab: 800x600(4:3).
3. I sort of ignored these issues and proceeded with the installation. However, I realized something was wrong when **Download updates while installing Ubuntu** was disabled (grey-ed out) and I couldn't see any hard drive partitions on the next screen.

My system specs are:
core i7, number of cores: 6
16GB RAM
Nvidia GTX 1660Ti graphics card, windows 10.
It is Asus GU502LU gaming laptop.

Need some help identifying the issue here.
Thanks!

Comment: The Try Ubuntu is there to make sure your hardware works before installing and having problems after.  We will need at least your computer make and model and any other information you can give before even trying to help without given wild guesses.  Might just need a newer version, 18.04 or 20.04.  You tried to install on a system giving you at least four problems.

Comment: Hi, apologies for providing insufficient information. I have edited my post and added the system specs.

Comment: If this is newer computer or maybe just a couple years old, would suggest using 18.04 or 20.04 version of ubuntu, but only use the try option till everything works.  Make sure when shutting down windows that fast boot option is turned off, so ubuntu can see partitions better.  Might have to use a wired connection till ubuntu can install wireless driver.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried installing a later version of Ubuntu - 18.04 and didn't face the problems mentioned above.